# When searching for source what are the .dsc archives? It is enough with the tars for distribution?

Tags: downloads, source-code, websites, source, source-packages

When searching for source.what are the .dsc archives? It is enough with the tars for distribution? Dsc rchives need to be in the source too?

Comment: Can you tell just by viewing one?  that it's a *description* file ; with checksum/signature detail & more.